# Axon server vs Axon Spring Boot Starter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, axon

I want to know if I use Axon Spring Boot Starter and I use mongoDB like event Store , I do not need to startup the axon server ?

And what is Axon server and why I start it if I use axon event store and event Bus ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how exciting you are trying out Axon!

Axon Framework consists of three types of messages: Commands, queries and events. Axon Server is both an Event store implementation and a messaging server that routes the right message to the right application instance. This way you can build a microservice architecture.

A free variant is offered, but if you need high availability the Enterprise variant is recommended.

If you use another implementation for the event store, like MongoDB or MySQL, Axon server is not needed. MongoDB is the least efficient implementation, as is outlined in the referenced guide: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/mongo

Lastly, if you'd like to know more about the framework and how to use it we offer quite extensive youtube videos and even have an academy where you can take other courses. You can find out more about this on https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/getting-started/quick-start